# Select Folder with google Picker

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I'm using google the plugin Picker for Google Drive.
My idea is select only the folders and get its ID.

Currently not let me select them,now only enter into that directory.
I am using this code:

```
    function MenuCtrl($scope, $location, appId) {
    var onFilePicked = function (data) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            if (data.action == 'picked') {
                var id = data.docs[0].id;
                $location.path('/edit/' + id);
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.open = function () {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
        view.setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .setAppId(appId)
            .addView(view)
            .setCallback(angular.bind(this, onFilePicked))
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);


    };
    $scope.create = function () {
        this.editor.create();
    };
    $scope.save = function () {
        this.editor.save(true);
    }
}
```

How could I get selected folder without going inside it?

Thank you very much in advance and greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that from 15th Jan 2014, the Picker requires that an OAuthtoken is set, ie. you need to include " setOAuthToken(oauthToken)." in your PickerBuilder

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your response.
The oauth2 autentication it's working in the servlet layer.
Now I can view and select Files, and I get its ID.
But I need to choose/select the folders too.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Ah ok. DocsView.setSelectFolderEnabled(boolean) from https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference

Answer (score 37):

I solved the problem, this is the new Code:

```
$scope.open = function () {

        var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
          .setIncludeFolders(true) 
          .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
          .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);


        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .addView(docsView)
          .setCallback(callback)
          .build();

        picker.setVisible(true);
});
```

Thanks for the help and greetings!

Comment: Please note that now you also have to set oAuth token on picker for all the views by using `setOAuthToken(oauthToken)` and                  `setDeveloperKey(developerKey)`

Comment: This works great with the picker example here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs It includes getOAuthToken() to get the currenlty logged in users oauth. you still need a developer key, but don't have to manage oauth stuff.