# How does it display designate folder in Google Picker for Google Drive file?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I use the Google Picker API, and below is my code:

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(new google.picker.DocsView()).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
```

I want it to display designate folder initially and only shows the files and folders beneath it, how should I modify? Thanks!

Comment: You may check the [DocsView.setParent(string)](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView) method which  sets the initial parent folder to display. Here's a sample [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20393-google-file-picker-example) which might help. Also, as stated on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173883/select-folder-with-google-picker), note that you have to set oAuth token on picker for all the views by using `setOAuthToken(oauthToken)` and `setDeveloperKey(developerKey)`.

Comment: Thank @abielita, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the [DocsView.setParent(string)](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView) method which   sets the initial parent folder to display. Here's a sample [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20393-google-file-picker-example) which might help. Also, as stated on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173883/select-folder-with-google-picker), note that you have to set oAuth token on picker for all the views by using `setOAuthToken(oauthToken)` and `setDeveloperKey(developerKey)`.