# Google Picker Api JS Showing Drive files without folders

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I want to show files with folders, the use of the function below is just showing a list of files without folders.

```
// Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
function createPicker() {
  if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
   var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
        .setAppId(appId)
        .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
        .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
        .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .build();
     picker.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DocsView.setParent(string)](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView) method sets the initial parent folder to display. Here's a sample [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20393-google-file-picker-example) which might help. Also, as stated on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173883/select-folder-with-google-picker), note that you have to set oAuth token on picker for all the views by using `setOAuthToken(oauthToken)` and `setDeveloperKey(developerKey)`.