# Google Drive Picker API - How to find folder ID

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm completely new to Google Drive API!  I've managed to get the Google Drive Picker API to work and do most of what I need.  But here is my problem:  Consider two folders:

root/test1/folder1
root/test2/folder1

Everything in the API uses ID for files and folders.  How can I get the folder ID for those two "folder1" folders to use in .setParent?  All the examples I can find both for Picker and the Drive API in general use hard coded IDs!  I don't know where to start.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked the code sample in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173883/select-folder-with-google-picker)?

Comment: @jess That code works for JavaScript (web-based) usage of the file picker, any idea how to do this within an Android app using Java?